# sed regex with replace

Tags: php, regex, replace, sed

Given a file:

```
<?

$dbo = mysql_fetch_assoc();

$dbo->employee_id;

$dbo->employee_name;

$dbo->dirt;

$dbo->dirt23;

$dbo->dirt_2_3;

?>
```

and using sed to find and replace:

```
sed -e "s|$dbo->([\w\_]*)|$dbo['\1']|g" test.php
```

It always returns an error.  I've tried using apostrophes as container and escaping everything properly and using forward slash as the command delimiter, but to no avail.

Result should be:

```
<?

$dbo = mysql_fetch_assoc();

$dbo['employee_id'];

$dbo['employee_name'];

$dbo['dirt'];

$dbo['dirt23'];

$dbo['dirt_2_3'];

?>
```

Help, please.

Comment: You could use `mysql_fetch_object()`instead. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-object.php

Comment: I'm moving away from mysql_fetch_object.  It's slower than mysql_fetch_assoc, believe it or not.  And I want to have associative arrays to use for a specific purpose which isn't pertinent to the question asked.  Thanks tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few mistakes:

1. `\w` already includes underscore
2. `$` needs to be excaped
3. Square brackets need to be excaped
4. You're using `$` inside double quotes while be expanded by shell

Use following sed:

```
sed -r 's/(\$dbo->)([[:alnum:]_]+)(.*)$/\1["\2"]\3/g'
```

OR on OSX:

```
sed -E 's/(\$dbo->)([[:alnum:]_]+)(.*)$/\1["\2"]\3/g'
```

**For Using single quotes:**

```
sed -r "\$s/(dbo->)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(.*)$/\1['\2']\3/g"
```

Comment: Works, but only thing is I want to use ' instead of " resulting in ['\2'] but escaping the apostrophes doesn't work.  And I was trying to avoid :alnum: as another use I have for this doesn't support it.

Comment: Sure you can try: `sed -r "\$s/(dbo->)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(.*)$/\1['\2']\3/g"`

Comment: `I changed "\$s/ to "s/ and that worked as I wanted.

Another slight change was to eliminate the (.*)$ and \3:

sed -r "s/(dbo->)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\1['\2']/g" test.php

Making this line replace correct:

$dbo->['employee_name'] . ' ' . $dbo->employee_address;

Which wasn't part of the original file, but...  Needed.

Thanks to you and everyone else!
`

Comment: Final answer:  sed -r "s/$dbo->([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$dbo['\1']/g" test.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac OSX you need the -E switch instead of -e, and use the following command instead of what you have:

```
cat test.php | sed -E "s/dbo->([a-z_]*.*);/dbo[\'\1\']/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're escaping one character that doesn't need to be escaped, and not escaping another character that *does* need to be escaped. The **_** is not a regex metacharacter, but the **$** is (matches the end of the string). Make that:

```
sed -e "s|\$dbo->([\w_]*)|$dbo['\1']|g" test.php
```

BTW, it's the `\_` that's generating the error. The unescaped **$** wouldn't give you an error, it would just make the regex fail to ever match anything, because you're trying to match the end of the string and then some things after the end. But `\_` doesn't mean anything; it would have to be either `\\_` to include both backslash and underscore in the character class, or just `_` to include just underscore.

Comment: Tried it.  Failed.  Error is:  sed: -e expression #1, char 25: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Answer (score 0):

You can use this perhaps (basic mode):

```
sed "s/\$dbo->\([^;]\+\)/\$dbo['\1']/" file.php
```

Comment: -1 The `$dbo` in double quotes will be replaced by the shell.